# Widget disappears when i activate my child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, child-theming

We are using Wordpress theme and Child but When I activate my child theme, then all defined widget disappears.

How to keep my widget on the child theme ?

```
/*
 Theme Name:   ABC Child Theme
 Theme URI:    http://demo.abcd.com/abc/
 Description:  ABC Responsive Multipurpose WooCommerce Child Theme  
 Author:       abcd
 Author URI:   abcd Team
 Template:     abc
 Version:      1.0
 Text Domain:  abc-child
*/

/* Theme customization starts here
------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Then it is because your child theme is not configured correctly. Please, share style sheet header of child theme.

Comment: Hello BlueSuiter, we have added  style sheet header of child theme , So please you can check it and help me for solution.

Comment: Update your headers `Template:     <parent theme folder name>`

Comment: Sorry bluesuiter, We have already added name of parent theme folder in Template. please you give any me other advise?

Comment: Can I look in to your setup? I will try there to fix it.

Comment: You chat with me on Skype?

Comment: hmm bluesuiter1991

Answer (score 0):

Storing widgets is complex topic. Basically, it is such a multi-level-array-mess on the inside that very few people try to make sense of it.

As far as I understand it myself while we can manipulate sidebar names on the surface, deep inside it is getting deconstructed to numerical IDs. So when you switch between themes amount and order of available IDs shift for each theme and widgets go haywire.

Wordpress stores sidebars for each current themes in the database.So, when your Parent theme Switches to child theme it may possible that the widgets registered for your parent theme are not may available for your child theme.